# Groovy trait inheritance

Tags: groovy, traits

In the example below the trait `Bar` extends `Foo` and the assertions pass

```
trait Foo {
  def foo() { 'foo' }
}

trait Bar extends Foo {
  def bar() { 'bar' }
}    

class Test implements Bar {
}

assert new Test().foo() == 'foo'
assert new Test().bar() == 'bar'
```

If we change the definition of `Bar` to

```
trait Bar implements Foo {
  def bar() { 'bar' }
}
```

The assertions still pass. Is there any meaningful difference between one trait implementing another and extending another?

Answer (score 1):

`implements` is used in case of multiple inheritance.  I would not exepect any difference to `extends`:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_multiple_inheritance

> Alternatively, a trait may extend multiple traits. In that case, all super traits must be declared in the implements clause